# Как передать ссылку на стек

Tags: c#, классы, ссылки, стек

Как передать ссылку на стек

```
public class Deck
{
    public Stack<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public void Full()
    {
        Cards = new Stack<Card>();
        for (var suit = 0; suit <= Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suit)).Length - 1; suit++)
        {
            Data.CardPoints = 2;
            for (var name = 0; name <= Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardName)).Length - 1; name++)
            {
                var points = 0;
                if (name <= (int)CardName.Ten)
                {
                    points = Data.CardPoints;
                }
                if (name > (int)CardName.Ten && name != (int)CardName.Ace)
                {
                    points = Data.faceCardValue;
                }
                if (name == (int)CardName.Ace)
                {
                    points = Data.aceCardValue;
                }
                var card = new Card();
                card.Suit = (Suit)suit;
                card.Name = (CardName)name;
                card.Value = points;
                Cards.Push(card);
                Data.CardPoints++;
            }
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        Cards = new Stack<Card>(Cards.OrderBy(i => random.Next()));
    }
}
```

нужно использовать этот стек в разных классах, а конкретнее использовать card.Value

Comment: А в чем проблема? Свойство публичное, создайте экземпляр класса `Deck` и пользуйтесь: `var deck = new Deck(); deck.Full(); var cards = deck.Cards;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP да,мне надо создать один экземпляр ,но использовать одну и туже колоду надо в разных классах ,я ж не буду пересоздавать ее в разных классах по новому ,поэтому считаю что мне нужна ссылка

Comment: Нет, создайте один раз и потом везде используйте. Просто разместите ее в общедоступном месте. У вас какого типа проект? Консольный или десктопный?

Comment: @АндрейNOP консольный

Comment: @АндрейNOP я понял о чем Вы

Comment: сделайте за свойством статическое поле и сделайте ленивую инициализацию в свойстве. set для этого свойства вам вряд ли пригодится, я бы сделал get-only